# Is EGF-mediated proliferation symmetric?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-signaling

It's known that the MAPK signaling cascade (say, ERK) is downstream of EGFR in epithelial cells, and that EGFR activation can cause proliferation in some cell types in some situations. My question is the following: if an epithelial cell with active EGFR (and hence active ERK activity) divides, will the two daughter cells have the same amount of ERK activity as the parent, both have half as much ERK activity as the parent, or divide asymmetrically? I suppose ERK activity should be defined here as ERK phosphorylation... though I would certainly welcome better definitions!

If you need better context, I would be considering wound healing of mammalian epidermal skin. There are plenty of sources suggesting that in response to  a wound puncture, EGF is released and stimulates proliferation.

Thank you!